# "TypeError: start2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'" exeption in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I was trying to "play" a little bit with the python-telegram-bot python library but I'm having this error that continues to pop out every time I try to click the inline keyboard button.

Here's the code

```
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ContextTypes

from TOKEN import TOKEN


keyboard = [
    [InlineKeyboardButton("Start", callback_data="start")],
]

start_query_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


async def start(update, context):
    await update.message.reply_text("Hello World!", reply_markup=start_query_keyboard)

def start2(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> None:
    update.callback_query.edit_message_text("START", reply_markup=start_query_keyboard)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()

    app.add_handlers([CommandHandler("start", start), CallbackQueryHandler("start", start2)])

    app.run_polling(stop_signals=None)
```

Comment: Why does the function take `context` argument if it's not used? Just removed it... (i.e. `def start2(update: Update)`

Comment: please show the full traceback of the error message. Also `start2` should be a coroutine function, i.e. `async def start2`